# How to keep =SUM value of the cells (A1:A5) when deleting one of the cell value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with cells from A1 to A5 with values and formula in A6 with =SUM(A1:A5)
Lets say cell A1 is 5 and A2 is 2    so SUM value should be 7. When deleting the data from cell A1 how to keep SUM value 7. So SUM value needs to keep adding up no matter data in cells deleted or not.

Comment: You need to convert the formula to a value.  That is, you'll replace the `=SUM` with `7`.  You can do that by copying the cell with Ctrl-C, then doing a special paste with Ctrl-Shift-V.

Comment: Can this be automated somehow ?

Comment: Well, yes, but this is strictly a one-time thing.  Once you have converted it to a number, it's a number forevermore.  It won't ever be a SUM again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart < 6 && !e.value && e.oldValue) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Execution completed but nothing shows up